# How can I make half transparent view excluding FAB?

Tags: android

See this example screenshoe:
[bike inside FAB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4q6mB.png)

In my WebView, I also want to do something like this. Like, I've FAB inside Relative layout, and in Relative layout, trying to make transparent using this layout:

```
android:background="@drawable/bg_half_transparent"
```

but, it is transparenting, but when I scroll up bottom sheet it is showing white color.

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:behavior_hideable="false"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="80dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
    app:cardElevation="@dimen/dimen_8dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_half_transparent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
            android:tint="@color/colorWhite"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_drop_down_black_24dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fab"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:text="View Details"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBottomSheetTextview"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="3">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:text="Order Details"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBottomSheetTextview"
                        android:textSize="18dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:text="₹435.00"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBottomSheetTextview"
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Chicken Fried Rice 1x1"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBottomSheetTextview" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Paneer Tikka 1x2"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBottomSheetTextview" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:text="Delivery Address"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBottomSheetTextview"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Flat No 404, Skyline Apartments, Vizag - 500576"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBottomSheetTextview" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:background="#000"
                    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    android:text="PROCEED PAYMENT"
                    android:textColor="#fff" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

bg_half_transparent

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:bottom="10dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <size android:height="10dp" />
           <!-- <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />-->
            <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="35dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <size android:height="10dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/colorBottomSheetBackground" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the example image CoordinatorLayout is used.

```xml
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
         ...
         app:layout_anchor="@id/yourViewId"
         />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is tutorial on that: https://medium.com/android-bits/android-anchoring-views-to-bottom-sheet-9c9069caf7d4

[image]